# language for a simple web app

Tags: database, web-applications

i want to write a simple web app that can connect to databases and display simple text and images. I know a bit of programming - mainly C. Also i have a very short time frame for learning the language and technologies associated with it. Which language would be good/ also what would be a good starting point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know C, PHP should come naturally.

It's also:

- Widely deployed
- Easy to get started
- Built exclusively for the web
- Plenty of resources for learning

Comment: And also more readable, and that should be the main purpose of it's usage :)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/), especially the screencast on their homepage, “Creating a weblog in 15 minutes with Rails 2”.

The syntax is different from C but on the other hand there’s practically *no* learning curve for simple web applications.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get much simpler than PHP. It's got C-type syntax. It's available nearly everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to PHP, try [Python](http://www.python.org/) with [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/). It's very quick to learn, a much nicer language than PHP, and has a good community. The only issue is it's not as widely deployed as PHP. But if you control the server then that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

PHP syntax is similar to C and it won't take much time to build a simple app.
PHP is one of the easiest language i've known :).

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are talking about a web application you get involved into javascript stuff so I say you give node js a try because it's fast and it has a lot of tools that could be integrated into your application with a few commands